# Python PSD layers?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, layer, psd

I need to write a Python program for loading a PSD photoshop image, which has multiple layers and spit out png files (one for each layer).
Can you do that in Python? I've tried PIL, but there doesn't seem to be any method for accessing layers. Help.
PS. Writing my own PSD loader and png writer has shown to be way too slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Gimp-Python? http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html

You don't need Photoshop that way, and it should work on any platform that runs Gimp and Python. It's a large dependency, but a free one.

For doing it in PIL:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
im = Image.open("spam.psd")
layers = [frame.copy() for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im)]
```

Edit: OK, found the solution: https://github.com/jerem/psdparse

This will allow you to extract layers from a psd file with python without any non-python stuff.

Comment: +1 For `psdparse`! Seems like OP doesn't have to roll his/her own functionality :)

Comment: We've exhaused all of the options out there, I believe. You'll either have to roll your own, or use Gimp-Python.

Comment: Thats too bad. I might be able to write my own code, but it might end up too slow (Python). Any suggestions what to try? i guess PIL uses plugin based approach so I could try that. There was a reply with example plugin, but it got removed

Comment: Maybe try and get in touch with the psdparse author, or at least use his module as a basis. No reason to start completely from scratch. Please accept my answer if I've helped.

Comment: That's a good idea. Er, how to "accept" answer? Id vote, but I can't yet

Answer (score 3):

Use psd_tools in Python

```
from psd_tools import PSDImage

psd_name = "your_name"
x = 0
psd = PSDImage.open('your_file.psd')

for layer in psd:
    x+=1
    if layer.kind == "smartobject":
        image.conmpose().save(psd_name + str(x) + "png")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the win32com for accessing the Photoshop with Python.
Possible pseudo code for your work:

1. Load the PSD file
2. Collect all layers and make all layers VISIBLE=OFF
3. Turn one layer after another, mark them VISIBLE=ON and export to PNG

```
    import win32com.client
    pApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.Application')

    def makeAllLayerInvisible(lyrs):
        for ly in lyrs:
            ly.Visible = False

    def makeEachLayerVisibleAndExportToPNG(lyrs):
        for ly in lyrs:
            ly.Visible = True
            options = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.PNGSaveOptions')
            options.Interlaced = False
            tf = 'PNG file name with path'
            doc.SaveAs(SaveIn=tf,Options=options)
            ly.Visible = False

    #pApp.Open(PSD file)
    doc = pApp.ActiveDocument
    makeAllLayerInvisible(doc.Layers)
    makeEachLayerVisibleAndExportToPNG(doc.Layers)
```

Comment: win32com is for Windows

Answer (score 1):

Using the win32com plugin for python (available here: http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/) You can access photoshop and easily go through your layers and export them.

Here is a code sample that works on the layers within the currently active Photoshop document, and exports them into the folder defined in 'save_location'.

```
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch

#Save location
save_location = 'c:\\temp\\'

#call photoshop
psApp = Dispatch('Photoshop.Application')

options = Dispatch('Photoshop.ExportOptionsSaveForWeb')
options.Format = 13   # PNG
options.PNG8 = False  # Sets it to PNG-24 bit

doc = psApp.activeDocument

#Hide the layers so that they don't get in the way when exporting
for layer in doc.layers:
    layer.Visible = False

#Now go through one at a time and export each layer
for layer in doc.layers:

    #build the filename
    savefile = save_location + layer.name + '.png'

    print 'Exporting', savefile

    #Set the current layer to be visible        
    layer.visible = True

    #Export the layer
    doc.Export(ExportIn=savefile, ExportAs=2, Options=options)

    #Set the layer to be invisible to make way for the next one
    layer.visible = False
```

Answer (score 1):

There are also https://code.google.com/p/pypsd/ and https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools Python packages for reading PSD files.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/antipalindrome/Photoshop-Export-Layers-to-Files-Fast

This is not in python, but the suggested solutions here proved more challenging for me than the above script. If you want the capacity to do more than just export layers to individual files, you're probably better off using the other options here. But if you only care about exporting layers to files, this script works easily and very quickly.